# Is it possible to write some logic for a viewcell and get a value from this this viewcell field?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datatemplate

Is it possible to create a `ListView` with `ViewCells` that will contain two `Buttons` and `Label`, first button will be "+", second "-" and a label will be a counter that will show how much "+" button has been tapped.

Then I want to be able to get from my listview an item that is binded to this viewcell and information about how much this item has been selected.

For now I created a `StackLayout` filled with `Views` thats "mocks" a `Viewcells`. This solution is so bad for many items because I have to create lots of `Views` (it takes few seconds).

So I would like to solve the problem using a `ListView` but I have no idea how to achive this. Or maybe you have a better solution than using a listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be trivial.  First, create a data structure to hold your data

```
public class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    } 

  private double _count;
  public double Count 
  { 
    get
    { return _count; }
    set
    { 
      _count = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}

List<MyData> data { get; set; }
```

you will need to initialize it with as many rows as your want to display in your list.  The create a template with a Label and Buttons that are bound to your Count property

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" >
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="{Binding Count}" />
          <Button Clicked="Increment" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="+" />
          <Button Clicked="Decrement" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="-" />            
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

in your code-behind

```
protected void Decrement(object sender, EventArgs args) {
  var b = (Button)sender;
  var data = (MyData)b.CommandParameter;
  data.Count--;
}

protected void Increment(object sender, EventArgs args) {
  var b = (Button)sender;
  var data = (MyData)b.CommandParameter;
  data.Count++;
}
```

finally, use binding or direct assignment to set the List's ItemsSourcee

```
listView.ItemsSource = data;
```

Comment: But I dont want to use stepper. I would like to use two styled buttons